# Why i can't use random value node as input for rotation in Transform Geometry in Geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Why is this not possible? I am trying to use random value as random rotation, i even tried align euler to vector node, it also shows red line[image: Why this red line?]

Comment: What are you trying to randomize, what is your goal here? There's a single sphere connected to the geometry, you can't randomize a single element.

Comment: You need to plug a single value node in the ID input to make the Random Value node a scalar (round socket) instead of a field (diamond socket). @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think it makes sense when you plug the Seed into a group input socket to be able to change from the modifier panel. However rotating a UV Sphere is likely to not be very noticeable :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wKiX.png

Comment: Hey guys, i understood the red line concept, thank you very much, what i was trying is to have some random rotation on my object, but i got it now!